# Android CameraX (Java) Wrong preview orientation

Tags: java, android, android-camerax

I ported CameraX from Kotlin to Java but my preview (TextureView) is correct only once opened as landscape. When I try to rotate (to portrait) the preview is distorted (maybe 90 degrees).
I removed the android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" from manifest else also first preview appears wrong.
Any other call to updateTransform() does not work, also changing rotation valkues make my TextureView smaller and do not solve the distortion.
I'm asking because most code is in Kotlin and I'm not finding a working solution in Java.
Here the code:

```
package com.sweetieapps.librarianpro;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.camera.core.CameraX;
import androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture;
import androidx.camera.core.ImageCaptureConfig;
import androidx.camera.core.ImageProxy;
import androidx.camera.core.Preview;
import androidx.camera.core.PreviewConfig;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.media.Image;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Rational;
import android.util.Size;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;


public class CameraXActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 10; //arbitrary number, can be changed accordingly
    private final String[] REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = new String[]{"android.permission.CAMERA","android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"};//array w/ permissions from manifest
    private TextureView txView;
    ImageView imgRotation, imgCapture;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.camerax);

        txView = findViewById(R.id.txvCameraXViewFinder);
        imgRotation = findViewById(R.id.imgCameraXRotation);
        imgCapture = findViewById(R.id.imgCameraXCapture);

        ImageView imgMask = findViewById(R.id.imgCameraXMask);

        if(Variables.PictureMode == Variables.PictureModes.User){
            imgMask.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else{
            imgMask.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        if(allPermissionsGranted()){
            startCamera(); //start camera if permission has been granted by user
        } else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS);
        }

        imgRotation.setOnClickListener(v ->
                updateTransform());
    }

    private void startCamera(){
        //make sure there isn't another camera instance running before starting
        CameraX.unbindAll();

        /* start preview */
        int aspRatioW = txView.getWidth(); //get width of screen
        int aspRatioH = txView.getHeight(); //get height
        Rational asp = new Rational(aspRatioW,aspRatioH); //aspect ratio
        Size screen = new Size(aspRatioW,aspRatioH); //size of the screen

        //config obj for preview/viewfinder thingy.
        PreviewConfig pConfig = new PreviewConfig.Builder().setTargetAspectRatio(asp).setTargetResolution(screen).build();
        Preview preview = new Preview(pConfig); //lets build it

        //to update the surface texture we have to destroy it first, then re-add it
        preview.setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener(
                output -> {
                    ViewGroup parent=(ViewGroup)txView.getParent();
                    parent.removeView(txView);
                    parent.addView(txView,0);
                    txView.setSurfaceTexture(output.getSurfaceTexture());
                    updateTransform();
                });

        /* image capture */
        //config obj, selected capture mode
        ImageCaptureConfig imgCapConfig = new ImageCaptureConfig.Builder().setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CaptureMode.MAX_QUALITY)
                .setTargetRotation(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation()).build();


        final ImageCapture imgCap = new ImageCapture(imgCapConfig);

        imgCapture.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            imgCap.takePicture(new ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCaptureSuccess(ImageProxy image, int rotationDegrees) {
                    //ByteBuffer bb = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                    //byte[] buf = new byte[bb.remaining()];
                    //bb.get(buf);
                    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                    if(image.getImage() != null){
                        //img.setImageBitmap(imageToBitmap(image.getImage()));
                        Variables.bitmap = bitmapRotate(imageToBitmap(image.getImage()));
                        image.close();
                        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
                        finish();
                    }
                    else{
                        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
                        finish();
                    }
                }
                /*
                @Override
                public void onError(
                        ImageCapture.UseCaseError error, String message, @Nullable Throwable cause) {

                    // silently ingore error
                }

                 */
            });
            /*
            //img.setImageBitmap(txView.getBitmap());

             */
            /*
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
            imgCap.takePicture(file, new ImageCapture.OnImageSavedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onImageSaved(@NonNull File file) {
                    String msg = "Photo capture succeeded: " + file.getAbsolutePath();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull ImageCapture.UseCaseError useCaseError, @NonNull String message, @Nullable Throwable cause) {
                    String msg = "Photo capture failed: " + message;
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if(cause != null){
                        cause.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            */
        });
        /* image analyser

        ImageAnalysisConfig imgAConfig = new ImageAnalysisConfig.Builder().setImageReaderMode(ImageAnalysis.ImageReaderMode.ACQUIRE_LATEST_IMAGE).build();
        ImageAnalysis analysis = new ImageAnalysis(imgAConfig);

        analysis.setAnalyzer(
            new ImageAnalysis.Analyzer(){
                @Override
                public void analyze(ImageProxy image, int rotationDegrees){
                    //y'all can add code to analyse stuff here idek go wild.
                }
            });

        //bind to lifecycle:
        CameraX.bindToLifecycle(this, analysis, imgCap, preview);
        */
        CameraX.bindToLifecycle(this, imgCap, preview);
    }


    private void updateTransform(){
         //compensates the changes in orientation for the viewfinder, bc the rest of the layout stays in portrait mode.
         //methinks :thonk:
         //imgCap does this already, this class can be commented out or be used to optimise the preview
        Matrix mx = new Matrix();
        float w = txView.getMeasuredWidth();
        float h = txView.getMeasuredHeight();

        float centreX = w / 2f; //calc centre of the viewfinder
        float centreY = h / 2f;

        int rotationDgr;
        int rotation = (int)txView.getRotation(); //cast to int bc switches don't like floats

        switch(rotation){ //correct output to account for display rotation
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                rotationDgr = 0;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                rotationDgr = 90;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                rotationDgr = 180;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                rotationDgr = 270;
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }
        mx.postRotate((float)rotationDgr, centreX, centreY);
        txView.setTransform(mx); //apply transformations to textureview
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        //start camera when permissions have been granted otherwise exit app
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS){
            if(allPermissionsGranted()){
                startCamera();
            } else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions not granted by the user.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean allPermissionsGranted(){
        //check if req permissions have been granted
        for(String permission : REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS){
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private Bitmap imageToBitmap(Image image){
        ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
        buffer.get(bytes);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length, null);
    }

    private Bitmap bitmapCrop(Bitmap bitmap){
        return bitmapCompress(Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0,0,bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getWidth()));
    }

    private Bitmap bitmapRotate(Bitmap bitmap){
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(90);
        if(bitmap.getHeight() < bitmap.getWidth()){
            if(Variables.PictureMode == Variables.PictureModes.User){
                return bitmapCrop(Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true));
            }
            else{
                return bitmapCompress(Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true));
            }

        }
        else{
            if(Variables.PictureMode == Variables.PictureModes.User){
                return bitmapCrop(bitmap);
            }
            else{
                return bitmapCompress(bitmap);
            }
        }
    }

    private Bitmap bitmapCompress(Bitmap bitmap){
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, stream);
        Bitmap compressedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(stream.toByteArray()));
        int width, height;
        width = compressedBitmap.getWidth() / 5;
        height = width * 8;
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.getWidth(), height, true);
        return bitmapScale(scaledBitmap);
    }

    private Bitmap bitmapScale(Bitmap bitmap){
        //Matrix
        int maxHeight = 500;
        int maxWidth = 500;
        float scale = Math.min(((float)maxHeight / bitmap.getWidth()), ((float)maxWidth / bitmap.getHeight()));
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(scale, scale);
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(@NonNull Configuration newConfig)
    {
        Log.d("tag", "config changed");
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        updateTransform();
        int orientation = newConfig.orientation;
        if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
            //Log.d("tag", "Portrait");
            imgCapture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        else if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
            imgCapture.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            //Log.d("tag", "Landscape");
        //else
           // Log.w("tag", "other: " + orientation);
    }
}
```

And here the Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextureView
        android:id="@+id/txvCameraXViewFinder"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgCameraXMask"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineCameraX"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:srcCompat="@android:color/black"
        tools:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgCameraXCapture"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="24dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineCameraXCapture"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/shutter" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineCameraX"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.6" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineCameraXPortraitMode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.8" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgCameraXRotation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imgCameraXMask"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineCameraXPortraitMode"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/take_in_portrait_mode" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineCameraXCapture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.85" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem a year ago with CameraX (Kotlin) and I had to refactor whole app because of this bug.
And after all I found (with Git) that once someone added to `manifest` this string:

> android:hardwareAccelerated="false"

By default it's `hardwareAccelerated="true"`, and after deleting this field, my Camera had worked properly.

Hope it'll help someone.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `updateTransform()` method is only correcting the preview by rotating it so that it matches the UI orientation. Preview distortion usually occurs when the size of the camera preview output is different that the size of the preview surface, to get past this issue the TextureView must be scaled appropriately to fit the preview within its bounds, or you can update the TextureView's SurfaceTexture by applying a transformation on it using a Matrix (like what you're doing with the rotation).

Given the different camera hardware levels, the numerous Android manufacturers and the various ways things can go wrong, getting the preview right isn't easy. The camerax library comes with a view artifact (androidx.camera.view) which contains a PreviewView class, it's advised to use it instead of a TextureView, as it tries to solve these issues under the hood. Using it looks like this.

In your layout file, include a PreviewView.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView 
        android:id="@+id/previewView"
        ... />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Then after you create a Preview use case, hook it up with PreviewView's PreviewSurfaceProvider.

```
final Preview preview = new Preview.Builder().build();
preview.setPreviewSurfaceProvider(previewView.getPreviewSurfaceProvider());
```

Keep in mind that the view artifact is still in alpha and still under development, so it may still have a couple of issues. But in general it addresses many preview issues developers face (including preview distortions).

Comment: One would probably expect that - but it's currently not the case. Down-voting me without a reason doesn't make this religious statement a quality answer, _which one could reproduce_. Have you ever tried that?

Comment: For me the Preview of CameraX is coming in half screen only, what could be the issue? However same code in another sample App is working correctly